# How to deal with the parameter of a route?

Tags: node.js, express

I configured some routes :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/isAccessible/:orgaId', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send("------ param = "+orgaId);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then inside an ejs file :

```
<script>
  function isOrganisationAccessible(orgaId) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/organisation/isAccessible/"+orgaId,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "text",
      success : function(data, status, xhr) {
        return data;
      },
      error : function(xhr, status, error) {
        return "";
      }
    });
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("test = "+isOrganisationAccessible("xxx"));
  });
</script>
```

At runtime I get `undefined` ! So how to retrieve the parameter passed to the route ?

Comment: could it have to do with the fact that the route paths are entirely different?

Comment: yes , the last parameter is the ID column from database.

Comment: I mean, you're trying to POST to `/organisation/isAccessible/` but your route is defined as `/isAccessible/`

Comment: it is to post to `/organisation/isAccessible/:orgaId` ; I already configured the routes in the entry point js.

Comment: It looks like you are getting `undefined` because the `isOrganisationAccessible` function is asyncronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue you're having is that `isOrganisationAccessible` is asyncronous.
Returning the data from the `success` function is not having the result you're expecting
because the data is not returned from `isOrganisationAccessible`, only from the `success`
function. `isOrganisationAccessible` will always return `undefined`.

You can address this by using a promise:

```
function isOrganisationAccessible(orgaId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/organisation/isAccessible/"+orgaId,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "text",
      success : function(data, status, xhr) {
        resolve(data);
      },
      error : function(xhr, status, error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Then resolve the promise to check the result:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  isOrganisationAccessible("xxx").then((data) => {
    alert(data)
  })
})
```

Comment: That source of the problem was not to do with asynchronous client side code, but handling the params in express. The neighboring answer solved it.

Comment: On second though, OP _was_ looking to alert it client-side. Ha, both answers are needed to arrive to the end state.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `orgaId` directly. You need to access it like this :

```
req.params.orgaId
```

update: 
I tested this simple app and it is working fine on /isAccessible/abc
I tested with the get query but with post also it should be fine. Also, why are you using post when you are not sending any data?

```
const express = require('express');  

let app = express();  

// Function to handle the root path
app.get('/isAccessible/:orgaId', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send("------ param = "+req.params.orgaId);
});

let server = app.listen(3000, function() {  
    console.log('Server is listening on port 3000')
});
```

Comment: still get `undefined` !

Comment: can you do a console print inside isOrganisationAccessible the value of orgaId and see if there the value is taken correctly or not ?